# NSDate from String Conversion

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Trying to convert the following string to an NSDate - I thought my DateFormatter was set correctly, but its not working:

```
NSString *dateToCheckString = @"Friday, Dec. 6, 2013 at 7:00 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"eeee, MMM. dd, yyyy at hh a"];
NSDate *dateToCheckNSDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateToCheckNSDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateToCheckString];

// Log it out to see the result:
NSLog(@"Conversion yielded: '%@'", [dateToCheckNSDate description]);
```

The output I get is `(null)`

Any ideas?

Comment: You should print the string with [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateToCheckNSDate], otherwise you will get a different hour in the output depending on your time zone.

Comment: Thanks! You made 2 good points (about using 'at' and about using `stringFromDate') - but David Rönnqvist's answer (below) added several more crucial pieces. So the right answer was to be had by piecing together your input with his input. Unfortunately since he posted his as an actual answer and you posted yours as a comment, I can only credit him ;-(  But you do deserve 50% of it, so thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not correct. `dd` is a padded day (06 in your example) so that should be just `d`. Also "7:00" does not match `hh` (which is padded hours). You are looking for `h:mm`

Comment: Thank you for this - it works! (Please do note that I also used @Jano's suggestions in his comment above along with your input to compose the final correct working code.)